Can you derive Fleming's right-hand rule from Fleming's left-hand rule?
Consider this system:

Fleming's right-hand rule quickly gives that there's an induced current flowing upwards.
I've also seen this argument using Fleming's left-hand rule a couple of times:

Consider an electron in the rod (we assume it's made of metal).
Because it's being moved towards the right, there is a current towards the left.
Fleming's left-hand rule now says that the electron feels a force downwards.
Because the electron moves down, and the conventional current is in the opposite direction of motion as the electron, there's a current flowing upwards.

This argument seems shaky to me, as though it's been created specifically knowing what the correct answer is. In particular, step 2 seems very dubious: there should be no way for there to be a current towards the left, since there is no wire in that direction. Furthermore, the left-hand rule is supposed to work given the presence of a current, and there is no current (before the wire starts to move). The right-hand rule on the other hand works with generators, which this system presumably is, so it is the appropriate one to use.
Is the argument above robust? Can we derive Fleming's right-hand rule using the left-hand rule in this fashion?


In particular, step 2 seems very dubious: there should be no way for there to be a current towards the left, since there is no wire in that direction.

The electrons still have a velocity component to the right, so they feel a magnetic force downward.

Is the argument above robust? Can we derive Fleming's right-hand rule using the left-hand rule in this fashion?

Yes, since using your left hand accounts for the negative charge in $F=qv\times B=-ev\times B$. The direction of $v\times B$ is determined by the right hand rule. You can account for the negative sign by either taking the opposite direction, or just using your left hand from the start.
